# How translate it? Intensedebate

Tags: plugins, comment-form

http://www.part.lt/img/4490330b04db19a9043999a460246e39489.JPG (IMG)

Look at yellow background.
How translate it, to Lithuanian lang?

Thanks!

I using IntenseDebate comments system.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the code for the *IntenseDebate comments system* and make sure where the *Comments* variable is initiated it looks like this

```
__("Comments", "your-theme"),
```

A double under-score denotes it to be translated. "Comments" is the interface element and "your-theme" is the theme translation initiator that should be in you functions.php theme file

```
// Make theme available for translation
// Translations can be filed in the /languages/ directory
load_theme_textdomain( 'your-theme', TEMPLATEPATH . '/languages' );
```